How to tell rpmbuild to install package A only when packages B C D are not installed?
I try to build an RPM package on RHEL8 with rpmbuild version 4.14.3.
This package shall have a dependency, that at least OpenJDK 1.8.0 is installed.
This OpenJDK 1.8.0 shall not be installed if java-11-openjdk or java-17-openjdk or java-21-openjdk are installed.
# rpm -qa | grep java
java-11-openjdk-devel-11.0.23.0.9-3.el8.x86_64
tzdata-java-2024a-1.el8.noarch
javapackages-filesystem-5.3.0-1.module+el8+2447+6f56d9a6.noarch
java-11-openjdk-11.0.23.0.9-3.el8.x86_64
java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.23.0.9-3.el8.x86_64
...


When yum install my package:
Dependencies resolved.
===================================
 Package                           
===================================
Installing:
 packageblabla         
Installing dependencies:
 java-1.8.0-openjdk                
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel          
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless       
Installing weak dependencies:
 gtk2      

The SPEC-file:
%{?_with_rhel8:Requires: (( java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel or java-11-openjdk-devel ) and ( java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel or java-17-openjdk-devel ) and ( java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel or java-21-openjdk-devel )) }

I tried with "unless" following https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/boolean_dependencies.html
But rpmbuild complains that I shall use "or".
error: line 150: Illegal context for 'unless', please use 'or' instead: Requires: (( java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel unless java-11-openjdk-devel ) and ( java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel unless java-17-openjdk-devel ) and ( java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel unless java-21-openjdk-devel ))


Additionally the build is also then needed for RHEL7, which comes with rpm version 4.11.
Kind regards,
Marcus

You are looking for the Conflicts directive in your spec. Consider adding it in this manner:
Conflicts: java-11-openjdk
Conflicts: java-17-openjdk
Conflicts: java-21-openjdk

Source:  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Conflicts
